# How does the set of complex numbers (resp., nonzero complex numbers) form a group under addition (resp., multiplication)?

Tags: group-theory

How is a complex number a group under addition.

How is a complex number a group under multiplication(without zero)

Comment: @chisom chinwuko: Assuming, as Ross does, that you meant "the set of all complex numbers" and "the set of all complex numbers without zero", then the answer is: in the obvious way.

Comment: The title should be changed.

Answer (score 6):

A complex number is not a group under addition.  The set of all complex numbers is a group under addition.  Just look at the definition of a group and see that you can verify the axioms.  Similarly for the set of complex numbers without zero and multiplication.